# London AvailabilityDomain could not be inferred from the Request

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am pretty sure this is something trivial, but I am a bit stuck with this.

I am trying to create an instance in Oracle Cloud in `uk-london-1` region via OCI CLI tool.
I am getting

```
"code": "InvalidParameter",
"message": "AvailabilityDomain could not be inferred from the Request",
```

The command I am trying to use:

```
oci compute instance launch --availability-domain lMrS:UK-LONDON-1-AD-1 --compartment-id <myid> --shape VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro --subnet-id <subnetid> --image-id Canonical-Ubuntu-22.04-2022.06.16-0
```

I got the list of AD's via CLI

```
~$ oci iam availability-domain list
{
  "data": [
    {
      "compartment-id": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..###",
      "id": "ocid1.availabilitydomain.oc1..###",
      "name": "lMrS:UK-LONDON-1-AD-1"
    },
    {
      "compartment-id": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..###",
      "id": "ocid1.availabilitydomain.oc1..###",
      "name": "lMrS:UK-LONDON-1-AD-2"
    },
    {
      "compartment-id": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..###",
      "id": "ocid1.availabilitydomain.oc1..###",
      "name": "lMrS:UK-LONDON-1-AD-3"
    }
  ]
}
```

And it is the same list of AD names I see in the Web UI.

Also I have similar error when trying to follow Oracle Cloud "Terraform: Create a Compute Instance" tutorial.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you subscribe to the London region through the console?

Also, you will need the OCID of the Ubuntu image, not the name

Comment: Thanks for having a look! It looks like I am. ``` ~$ oci iam region-subscription list { "data": [ { "is-home-region": true, "region-key": "LHR", "region-name": "uk-london-1", "status": "READY" } ] } ``` I will get image ocid, that is an easy fix, just need to figure out this AD stuff out.

Comment: Try using AD-2. 


oci compute instance launch --compartment-id $compartment_id --availability-domain lMrS:UK-LONDON-1-AD-2 --display-name "name" --subnet-id ocid1.subnet.xxxx --image-id ocid1.image.xxx --shape VM.Standard1.1 --wait-for-state RUNNING --config-file ./oci/config --metadata "{\"ssh_authorized_keys\": \"$(cat ${KEYPATH}.pub | tr -d '\n')\"}"

Comment: One of the reasons of these errors are compartment ocid or any other ocid may not be correct. This error message can be misleading actually. Make sure all OCIDs are correct by running a get command.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@urawesome](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6553200/urawesome), my compartment-id was wrong and the error returned is a bit misleading as well.

I used actual Compartment name from web UI, when it should have been `ocid1.tenancy.###` Mainly focused on availability-domain thinking that other parameters will throw different errors if they are invalid.

Correct `compartment-id` aka `tenancy-id` solved the issue.

Thanks!